# JQuery selector for inline style property

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I would like to use a jquery to select the following span:

```
<span id="RequiredFieldValidator1" class="validationerror" style="color: Red; display: none;">*</span>
```

But not select the following span which differs from the original in that the style attribute has a display property whose value is inline instead of none.

```
<span id="RequiredFieldValidator2" class="validationerror" style="color: Red; display: inline;">*</span>
```

I am aware inline styles are evil but an asp.net web forms validator control is generating it and doing a lot of good as well as evil.

Can this be done using jquery selectors? I'm new to jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('.validationerror:hidden')
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me figure out how to select the first hidden tr element in a table. Actually, what surprises me is that the hidden selector works for the display attribute. I'd assumed that it was for the visibility attribute only.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("span[style*=inline]")
```

will select all span elements with the style attribute which has the value "inline" in it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response you actually answered my question as asked but the other solution was more elegant.

Comment: This doesn't work

<html><head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  alert($("span[style*=inline]").length);
 }
 )
</script>
<span id="RequiredFieldValidator2" class="validationerror" style="color: Red; display: inline;">*</span>    
</body>
</html>

Comment: It worked for me when I put inline in quotes: $("span[style*='inline']")

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this to add\remove an error style to the parent of the validation error control to highlight the control that caused the error and the validation message.

```
$('input').change(function() {
  $(".validationError[style*=hidden]").parent().removeClass("error");
  $(".validationError[style*=visible]").parent().addClass("error");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an advise for selecting server side controls too

```
document.getElementById("<%=txtFirstName.ClientID %>");
```

or

```
$("#'<%=txtFirstName.ClientID %>'");
```

or

```
$("[id$='_txtFirstName']");
```

Answer (score -1):

embed the styles inside the classes and you have 2 class the use JQuery selector

```
$(".<ClassName>")
```